# Ways to share game(s) online

Tags: online

In this era of social networking, it is surprising there are no straight forward ways for sharing our games online.

Sharing means a possibility of sending a link to some one, who can just step through the game and the analysis easily or post it to facebook / twitter.

Having an embeddable player to put the game in our blog would be nice. But that's not the main thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question for documenting what I use. I will keep this answer updated as I discover more ways.

- [lichess](http://en.lichess.org/paste) This is the simplest and cleanest way I found. Just copy pgn text and paste. It generates a nice little shareable link. Very nice interface to playback the moves. As a bonus, it also provides automatic (stockfish) engine analysis identifying the inaccuracies, mistakes, and blunders for the whole game. (usually within few seconds!)
- [Chess Pastebin](http://www.chesspastebin.com/) is okay. It is good for games with minimal or no analysis. But the interface is cumbersome for games with a lot of analysis.
- [Chess Microbase](http://chessmicrobase.com) is good for storing many games.
- [NOT WORKING NOW] [ChessPost](http://chesspo.st) is nice and simple. Particularly useful for the purpose the question mentions.
- [PGN4Web](http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/home.html) provides a good interface for a broad number of applications.

Comment: Chess Microbase is excellent!

Answer (score 5):

In these times, sharing the [Movetext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#Movetext) section from a PGN (and the starting position if needed) is enough to recreate the game. People can view the game using their favorite method (e.g PGN viewer, real board or maybe *visualizing* the moves in their heads if they are prodigy enough).

But if you really want to just share a link that displays the game, my choice would be [LT-PGN-Viewer](http://www.lutanho.net/pgn/pgnviewer.html), just fill everything and then click *Make Gamelink*.

**Note:** there might be a limit on the number of moves you can pass, since the game is stored in the URL rather than saving the game somewhere and passing an ID). Also, a good idea is to shorten the link since it will probably be lengthy.

Comment: LT-PGN-Viewer is nice if the game to be sent in email. But some would prefer to have it hosted on the web and just send a link on IM or twitter.

Answer (score 3):

The puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/81359/11110) offers a light-weight alternative, [Apronus](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/). It's quite simple: paste the PGN, click the 'Absorb' button and then 'Link to share'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use [the game explorer on chess.com](http://www.chess.com/explorer/), there's a database, it compares your game to other games, searches for related openings, and you can get a link to page.

using game explorer to analyse your games is always free, however to see other games, you have to be a [premium member](http://www.chess.com/membership).

Also on [chess.com](http://chess.com), you have [the analysis board editor](http://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor), which is free and you can embed it in webpages. Click on "Game editor" tab -> "Embed" button.