# Online personalized database resource

Tags: database, online, annotation

I'm searching for the possibility of having my personal database of annotated games in the cloud, my games included. I already read [this post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/ways-to-share-games-online): 1) http://chessmicrobase.com/ looks nice, although basic, I already added a game, but the problems are that I cannot I add variants and I'm not very sure for how much time this site will be reliable. 2) http://www.chessgames.com/ is slow and ugly (java based) and I cannot add my own games, premium membership included. But the main problem is that is very slow.

I'll be happy also with a simple cross-platform chess edit application, with the same features and the possibility to integrate chess engines, but my main interest is in the online.

Comment: No _annotation_ tag: that's funny!

Comment: Found another possibility: http://www.365chess.com/view_game.php?g=2235437 but without annotations and variations, and that is a must :( ... Except maybe if the pgn format allows variations

Comment: While the `pgn` format allows, of course, variations, 365chess.com doesn't know to interpret them. The editing process for them is directly modifying the `pgn` content.

Answer (score 1):

[Chess Microbase](http://chessmicrobase.com/) is the only thing I found.

- You can have 3 databases for free which is probably enough in most cases.
- You can also share the link to the game.
- Supports importing and exporting with PGN.
- Has support for annotations.
- I am using it for couple of years now (I think). It seems reliable and seem to get new features. Of course, take backups.

Comment: Has the annotation support for variations ? For instance, I used the triangle symbol for "With the idea ..." but I didn't succeed to add ... the idea

Comment: I have tried with text annotations. It is fine. But not sure how to input symbols. If it is part of unicode, you will probably succeed there.